# ideas for sparse 4D array of bytes?

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, ip-address

I need to store about 60000 IP-address-like things such that I can quickly determine if the store contains an address or return all the addresses that match a pattern like `3.4.*.*` or `*.5.*.*`. The previous implementation used `HashTables` nested four levels deep. It's not fully thread safe, and this is causing us bugs. I need to make this thread safe with locking on the outer layer, or I could change all those to `ConcurrentDictionaries`, but neither of those options seemed quite right. Using a byte for a key in a dictionary never felt quite right to me in general, especially a heavy-weight dictionary. Suggestions?

Comment: Does the list change or is it static?

Comment: 60,000 is a pretty small number, computationally speaking; enough so that the fixed overhead of nested HashTables is probably higher than just iterating through the entire list and checking every element for your criteria.  Try the simplest implementation, profile it, then see if you need to make it faster.  If so, you can speed things up with various indexes, but it might not even be necessary.

Comment: How random are the IP addresses? Do you expect to have entire subnets (so it is reasonable to store ip/netmask), or more likely it would be some single addresses?

Comment: The list changes as clients come and go. Also, my addresses don't follow the subnet and masking rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guava uses a prefix trie for storing IP lookup matches. You can see the code here:

https://code.google.com/p/google-collections/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/common/collect/PrefixTrie.java?r=2

This is Java code, but I'm sure you could easily adapt it to C#. The technique of a prefix trie is applicable independent of the language and gets you trailing wildcard matches for free. If you want arbitrary wildcards, you'll still need to implement that yourself. Alternatively, you could build a data structure similar to a [Directed acyclic word graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_word_graph) (DAWG). This will let you more directly implement the arbitrary wild card matches.

Comment: "trie" was the word I needed. Thanks.